# I wanted to download files whose name start with a particular string from a folder in an HTTPS link using c#

Tags: c#, https, ssis, webclient

I wanted to download files whose name start with a **particular string** from a folder in an **HTTPS** link using **c#**, 
for this example my file start with **test** but i dont know the **XXXX** characters

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");
webClient.DownloadFile("https://domain.com/testXXXX.zip", "d://file.zip");
```

i have already tested the code with a file whose name i already know and it worked perfectly

Any help please ?

Comment: You'll need some method of getting a file list from the server... plain and simple. If the server has no support for giving you such a file list, you're out of luck (unless you want to do ugly brute-forcing). And if it gives that list as web page, you're going to have to write code for reading and parsing that page to a list of filenames.

Comment: i've tested the code without the crendentials and its works correctly, any proposition to fetch the folder before start the downloads ?

Comment: As I said. That depends on how / if the server can give you a files list.

Answer (score 0):

please use this to get all file that meet ur crateria and then apend the to ur url

```
var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("").Where(x=>x.StartsWith("test"));
           foreach (var fi in fileEntries )
            {
                WebClient client = newWebClient();
                client .Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass");
                yourUrl=  yourUrl +fileName
                client.DownloadFileAsync(yourUrl, destinationhere);
            }
```

Comment: it's not working with the HTTPS link, cause i need the Credentials to get the files from the directory

Comment: then set the credential as u did in ur code.i knew u were going to inlude that part

Comment: i have edited my ans to include the credential.let me know if u still have isues

Comment: the problem is here : var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("").Where(x=>x.StartsWith("test")); 

i dont have access to the directory without the credentials so the function GetFiles will not got anything

Comment: I don't think Directory.GetFiles() works on remote websites _anyway_. It's for local file systems.

Comment: Nyerguds, do u have any idea to resolve this problem ?

Comment: @user3262030 Not without knowing what kind of site you're talking about. If the site doesn't give any kind of file listing, there's nothing you can do.